# API documentation preview of current class

Tags: java, eclipse, api, documentation, preview

I'm very new at Java programming and i've decided to take 1 step farther and move from bluej (which is "special" student oriented program) to eclipse.
I've been missing something i had really easily on bluej and that's the "documentation" view of the code im currently working on.
It's simply a switchable mode which i can see a page (identical to a class's API documentation) with a preview of my current done documentation on my code so i can follow changes and see how it looks.

Could anyone guide me through how do i do that on eclipse? i saw that there's some sort of live feed of that when u simply outline a method and such and i can see it on the Javadoc tab below but is it possible to generate a full API html peview?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that there is such a thing in Eclipse. There is a "Javadoc view" (`Window->Show view -> Javadoc`) but that is quite different, it shows the Javadoc doc of the "current" element in the editor, basically the same that is shown as a popup/tootiptext when you hover a method call.